# Ansible: Unable to escape double curly braces

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am performing some deployments using Ansible AWX.

At some point in time, I want to set a couple of parameterized (env var) urls as follows:

```
environment:
  SOME_URL: "https://{{ hostname }}/webpage/index.html#!/auth/passwordReset?token={% raw %}{{ token }}{% endraw %}"
```

This solution has been suggested in several ansible issues. e.g. [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/15892#issuecomment-327790503).

However in the job's output on `AWX` I keep getting:

> "msg": "'token' is undefined"

Using `AWX 1.0.4.130` and `Ansible 2.5.0`

**edit**: getting the exact same outcome when using the following escape method:

```
 environment:
      SOME_URL: "https://{{ hostname }}/webpage/index.html#!/auth/passwordReset?token='{{ '{{' }} token {{ '}}' }}'"
```

**Update**: The problem seems to be **specifically** related to env vars, because when I am escaping double curly braces in either of the above ways it works.

Comment: I would really appreciate an elaboration on the downvote

Answer (score 0):

try using "{{ '{{' }}" and "{{ '}}' }}" for printing curly braces.

fast example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    SOME_URL: 'https://aaaaa/webpage/index.html#!/auth/passwordReset?token={{ "{{" }}aaa{{ "}}" }}'

  tasks:
  - name: print it out
    debug:
      var: SOME_URL
```